# When the Customer is populated, refresh the suitelet and add a sublist in netsuite

Tags: netsuite

How would I go about this task, I already have a working Suitelet with a customer field however I need it to refresh and add a sublist when a customer is added

I've tried adding a client script to detect the change in the customer field but I don't know what to do after that. I am very new to NetSuite thanks for any and all help.

Comment: SubList will be created from a saved search result?

Comment: I believe, you'll need to work with a `serverWidget.Assistant`. Coding it, ain't that easy though. You've to properly understand the next, previous and finish action. https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4325849970.html

Answer (score 0):

On your client script, get the customer ID and pass it to your suitelet URL using [url.resolveScript](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4358672433.html). From there, after the Suitelet refreshes you have access to the customer ID where you could render a Sublist before displaying your form.